# Create a view pulling in content that matches user profile

Tags: views

Im am trying to create a view that pulls in content that matches to the user. This is done with two taxonomy fields that are added to the user profile and the content type. These are job role and speciality. I know how to set up the view to pull in content using just 1 of these fields but how can I get it so its an AND condition. I need to pull in content that has both the same job role and same speciality as the user. Is there anyway of achieving this through the views UI or do I need to alter the query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a **relationship** for Content: Taxonomy terms on node and using [hook_views_query_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) and  loading the users profile and adding two where clauses like so :

```
$query->add_where(0,"field_data_field_job_role.field_job_role_tid",$job,"=");

$query->add_where(0,"field_data_field_specialty.field_specialty_tid",$specialty,"=");
```

Answer (score 0):

With Drupal 7 and Views 3 you can match on multiple taxonomy terms using contextual filters. I posted about this on drupal.org [here](https://drupal.org/node/1762770#comment-6560430). Maybe it can be adapted to your particular situation.

Comment: Hi, thanks I've tried this but it seems to be an OR condition regardless of if i use a + or ,

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that using Views module as usual. In the edition of the view:

1. Look for the `Filter Criteria` section
2. Locate the button in the right.
3. Click on the arrow and you should see the link `And/OR, Rearrange`.
4. Click it and add the conditionals you need.

Hope this is what you're trying to achieve.